# How to call .sjs file from HTML?

Tags: javascript, marklogic, sjs

I just started learning programming using MarkLogic.
I followed documentation, created "sample.sjs" file like in below.
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/language#id_71272

```
xdmp.setResponseContentType("text/plain");
"hello"
```

How should I call this "sample.sjs" to display result in HTML?
Or should I better include HTML code inside "sample.sjs" file?

Answer (score 3):

Your SJS code must construct whatever content you want to return to the caller, including HTML. The content returned by your module becomes the response data.

There's a bit more robust example using JSON instead of HTML, here:

https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/sjs/http